# Dragging Asset from Asset Browser Rotates It 90 Degrees depending on View Angle

Tags: asset-browser, asset

Whenever I try to drag an asset from the browser, it will be rotated 90 degrees, instead of pointing upwards. It's pointed correctly if dragged onto a plane, but in the case I want to use it in, there'll rarely ever be a floor.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aw3BYUSdDcU

Comment: I cannot replicate the issue. Maybe you can share the asset file? you can use https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963), along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.